# x86(x87) floating point operation operands (theory)

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, fpu, x87

I'm following https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Floating_Point to learn basic FPU operations.

For multiplication (calculating square in this case), it uses:

```
fmul   st0, st0; //
```

But i read that the FPU is implemented as a stack, and operates on the top or (top - 1) of stack.
So i assumed it should be something like

```
fld qword [c]
fmul st(0)
fmulp st(1)
```

Why is that the FPU allows indirect register access, through stack indices?
It feels like it goes against the stack vs register arguments.

Comment: One of the arguments to each x87 instruction is implicitly `st0`, the other one can be any stack register or memory operand.

Answer (score 3):

That's not "indirect", it's still direct: using a register number embedded in the machine code.  Using 1-explicit-operand machine code lets the code be more compact,  which was a benefit for the design back in the ancient days when 8087 was designed.  The source or destination operand has to be `st0`, with the opcode implying whether it's src or dst.

One register-number is still hard-coded into most instructions, and you can do `fmul st, st6` but not `fmul st4, st6`.    Have a look at the [available encodings of `fmul`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fmul:fmulp:fimul):

- `D8 /1    FMUL m32fp` memory-source, no stack adjustment
- `DC /1    FMUL m64fp` same.
- `D8 C8+i  FMUL ST(0), ST(i)` - reg,reg with st0 as the destination
- `DC C8+i  FMUL ST(i), ST(0)` - reg,reg with st0 as the source
- `DE C8+i  FMULP ST(i), ST(0)` - reg,reg and then pop st0 out of the stack
- `DE C9    FMULP` - just a special case of the previous one, `fmulp st1, st0`

So 3 opcode bytes (and a variety of ModRM encodings) allow memory or register source, or reg,reg with a higher destination.

**The "stackiness" is there to save machine-code size, not to make it a "pure" stack machine.  That would suck for performance: it would require wasting a lot of instructions to get the desired data into st0, st1.**  And would make most of the register stack unusable; almost all code would just have to store/reload most results to memory instead of keeping them higher in the register stack.

---

Also, your `fmul` with no operands example is broken.  If you assemble that with NASM , `fmul` assembles to `DE C9  fmulp  st(1),st` for some strange reason, so that would read the top *two* registers from the x87 stack, but one of them is empty so you'll get NaN. You would have needed an `fld st0` first, if you wanted to use `fmulp`

Intel's manual doesn't list a form of `fmul` with no explicit operands, only `fmulp`.  To square st0 twice, you'd `fmul st0` / `fmul st0`.  That gives you `d8 c8   fmul   st,st(0)`